# www being served on iis, non-www being served on apache?

Tags: iis-7, apache2

Here is the problem, if you visit the site [directorybest.net](http://directorybest.net) you will see the correct website (which is defined in apache). But if you go to the www version of the site a catch all site for and from IIS is displayed. I have no idea what this is causing this.

I have another site that already runs fine on apache from which I copied the info for DNS and vhost settings. I also have set the DNS up so that both sites point to the same ip address. Does anyone know why the www version of the site does not show the right website?

Here is the vhost information for both the working and non working site.

```
NameVirtualHost *

#non-working site

<VirtualHost *>
 ServerAdmin admin@email.com
 ServerName www.directorybest.net
 ServerAlias directorybest.net *.directorybest.net
 DocumentRoot "D:\WWW\DirectoryBest\2"
 DirectoryIndex index.php

 <Directory D:\WWW\DirectoryBest\2> 
             AllowOverride All 
 </Directory>

 # Logfiles
        ErrorLog  D:\WWW\DirectoryBest\2\logs\error.log
        CustomLog D:\WWW\DirectoryBest\2\logs\access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

#working site

<VirtualHost *>
 ServerAdmin admin@email.com
 ServerName www.directorybest.info
 ServerAlias directorybest.info *.directorybest.info
 DocumentRoot "D:\WWW\DirectoryBest\1"
 DirectoryIndex index.php

 <Directory D:\WWW\DirectoryBest\1> 
             AllowOverride All 
 </Directory>

 # Logfiles
        ErrorLog  D:\WWW\DirectoryBest\1\logs\error.log
        CustomLog D:\WWW\DirectoryBest\1\logs\access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I don't see a difference between "www.directorybest.net" and "directorybest.net".  Maybe you only see the problem from your test box?

Comment: Well that is interesting. I have tried remoting to a computer out side my building and trying the sites on that computer but i still receive the different websites. Maybe it has something to do with resolving the ip address?

Comment: Ok a couple of other people have confirmed that everything is fine now. I suspect it might be the DNS records not being fully updated. Going to wait to see if it fixes itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I was just informed that the company has had DNS problems before. And upon further checking the local DNS had not been updated and was still resolving to the old ip address.